# intellij idea, How to find package name from code?

Tags: intellij-idea, package

In eclipse when you copy a code from Internet for example and paste into IDE, when you put mouse on top of method, Eclipse shows this method belongs to what package ans class. So, you can by one click add it to code.

I have copy/pase following code into IntelliJ IDE:

```
double d1, d2;
Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
d1 = scannerObject.nextDouble();
d2 = scannerObject.nextDouble();
System.out.println("You entered " + d1 + " and " + d2);
```

My question is, is there a way like eclipse to add package and class name of `Scanner` into code instead of typing `import java.util.Scanner;` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press    `alt + enter` -> `import class` on class, and you will get list of possible packages

Comment: You can also use the optimize import Ctrl+Alt+O, this is similar to Eclipse support.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a useful preference "**Settings>Editor>Auto Import>Optimize imports on the fly**" you can switch on.

Regards